# generate UUID on object creation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to generate a unique ID when a new object is to create

I have a model called Product, which has a name and weight and price. I want to create a unique Id that begins with "TPK" + random 8 characters and add it to the products table. what's a simple method to achieve it?

Here is the current migration file

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :products do |t|
  t.string :weight
  t.string :product_name
  t.integer :price
  .......
```

I want to add another attribute to it called `product_code` and I want it to have a unique Id on creating starting with  `"TPK" + random 8` characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using migration only to update the Schema and leave the model logics inside the model. So first, you create a migration to add `product_code` to the products table. Then add a hook in Product model to create a default code:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :default_product_code

  private
  def default_product_code
    #your implementation
    #e.g. self.product_code = 'TPK' + SecureRandom.hex(4)
  end
end
```

Comment: You should also check the freshly generated code is unique before assigning it (and have a unique index on that column). But this answer is the spirit

Comment: @CodyCaughlan yes you're right. I focused on the approach and left out the implementation, which will need to take into account some more details such as uniqueness.